# What are the general approach on structuring or modeling the Istio policy around service in a repository?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Currently our GKE cluster consists of multiple services running in different namespace, each svc communicate with each other too. We're using:

- each service on different git repo
- each service repo contains: source code, its helm chart defining the app deployment and infra surrounding it (Service, Istio Ingress/Egress Gateway,etc), and has its own ci/cd (jenkinsfile).

Right now, I also want to incorporate Istio security policy to enforce security of svc-to-svc communication. I've understand basic concept of it. Now, my case is how put service policy to what repo.

For example: given that I have service A (client) communicating with Service B (server). Istio has 3 different kind of policy enforcement:

- mesh wide policy
- namespace wide policy
- service specific policy

Since our gke cluster is still in the early stage of using Istio and  I want to have little effort on central governance, I prefer to adopt **service specific policy**, so each service owner can govern the policy too.

I am thinking to put:

- the `Policy` (service specific policy) in each service repo who acts
  as a server. The reasoning behind this is `Policy` is enforcing incoming trafficPolicy to the service (not the outcoming).

But I am wondering how about the DestinationRule? From article Istio provides [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#globally-enabling-istio-mutual-tls)

> To configure the client side, you need to set destination rules to use mutual TLS. I

From quote above, I get the understanding that `DestinationRule` is the one who enforce the client side (who has istio side car container). So `DestionationRule` should be put on client service repo (in the given case, it is on Service A repo).

But of course, in the server side (service B repo), the team also want to have a certain load balancing and split traffic mechanism (canary, stable, versioning, etc), which can only be defined by `VirtualService` and `DestionationRule`.

Any thought about this? Does anyone has general pattern/approach on designing this policy manifest (istio yaml file) around service in a repository?

Comment: I found this [blog post](https://kublr.com/blog/implementing-a-service-mesh-with-istio-to-simplify-microservices-communication/) that might be helpful to You, unfortunately there is nothing about using repos.